# How to pass the attributes in ajax which can be accessed through params in the controller in ruby on rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

My index.html.erb file looks like:
index.html.erb

```
...
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">                                                
        <li class="list-group-item">
            Post --> <%= post.message %>                                                    
            <%= link_to "Like", 'javascript:void(0)', class: "btn btn-default like-right-position like-btn"%>                                                    
            <span class="like-right-position like-text">Likdfe</span>                                                
        </li>                                                
        <a class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-parent="#accordion1" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-post-<%= post.id %>"> Comments</a>                                            
    </h4>
</div>
...
```

And my application.js file is:

```
$('.like-btn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "like_user_post_path", 
        data: "",
        success: function(result){
            $(".like-text").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

I do not understand the concept of data attributes in html and how to pass it through ajax. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Why do not you use data field inside ajax block ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the description mentioned in the post, the data attrbutes are the ones which are sent as body for the following POST request via ajax.

```
$('.like-btn').click(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "like_user_post_path", 
    data: {"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"},
    success: function(result){
        $(".like-text").html(result);
    }
});
});
```

Above is an example where the field1 and field2 specify the keys from which you will be parsing over the controller to fetch the corresponding values.

Comment: How can we set the same data attributes in the link_to tag?

Comment: link_to "abc", abc_path(@abc.id, param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2'), method: :post

Comment: It would be great if you could mark it as a correct, if it was helpful so that others can benefit from the same.